# Java multiple instances of same class share the same running objects, but they shoud not

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm doing a multithreaded Java optimization algorhithm which initiates various instances of the same subclass, for time improvement reason. This subclass have itself other subclasses.

The algorhthm searchs though the search space for an optimal solution, by means of random movements. So, if i run several instances of it, i should take advantage of my system's cores and improve the search widing the search space.

I've noticed that the first instance runs well, but others seems to share the running objects of the first, picking the information they hold, even when it has finished.

Thats not what i want; i want any of the instances be insulated for the others.

I'm using Executor Services:

Code:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ExecutorCompletionService<float[][]> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<float[][]>(executorService);

IteratedGreedy[] ig = new IteratedGreedy[instances];
Future<float[][]>[] future = new Future[instances];

// launching instances:
for (int i=0; i<instances; i++)
    {       
    path = "\\" + i + ".txt";
    ig[i] = new IteratedGreedy(path);
    future[i] = service.submit(ig[i]);
    }

// retrieveing solutions:
for (int i=1; i<instances; i++)
    {
    solutions[i] = future[i].get();
        }
```

As you may think, the IteratedGreedy function has its own sublcasses inside.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you have having a problem with variables declared as `static` but you will have to show us the implementation of `IteratedGreedy` to be sure.

Comment: I have a static float[][] object, but i cannot declare it as non-static without giving the IDE an error. But not in IteratedGreedy, the static float[][] is inside a subclass it uses.

Comment: That implies you have a `static` method where you should have a non-static method.

Comment: Ok. I think i've done it. I removed the static as follow: removing the static tag. Then, the method wich uses the object, instead of picking it as a global variable, picks it as an argument. Thanks!

Comment: Good job fixing it by yourself!

Answer (score -1):

Problem is, somewhere in the code, theres a class with a global static variable:

```
static float[][] matrix;
```

And then, a method uses it:

```
SomeMethod()
    {
    int f = matrix[i][b];
    }
```

The solution is to change the way the method obtains the object:

```
float[][] matrix;

SomeMethod(float[][] matrix)
    {
    int f = matrix[i][j];
    }
```

Comment: No. The solution is to *not declare the variable as static.* And then make whatever code adjustments are necessary. Probably `SomeMethod()` is static when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Its likely you could just remove the `float[][] matrix` in `SomeMethod(float[][] matrix)` and it should pick up the instance variable. Incidently it should be `someMethod` not `SomeMethod`